# Java classpath used by Spring

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I know a way to print the classpath of a project at runtime like here:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/

But sometimes the main is even too late, for example when using spring.

Is there a way to print something(e.g. classpath) even before Spring starts the injection process?

Providing some context, i am running a unit test in spring as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/jmsAppContext.xml")
public class TestProjectProvisioningIntegration
{
....

}
```

It finds correctly the jmsAppContext.xml, but fails to find one of the properties files.

Comment: Give us some context. What kind of app are you talking about?

Comment: Is printing classpath need of your application or you need it just for testting?

Comment: I just need it for testing, i have a unit test that doesn't find the a properties files although i can see it and it's in one of the jar that the test clearly has in the classpath(supposedly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the same effect as you have in the link you posted, you could get the classpath in a static initializer (just do the same as the example, only then in a `static { ... }` block instead of a main method. The JVM will execute the static initializer first, before loading any other classes your class depends on (other than the classes you reference in the static initializer).